# Regular Expression not matching in notepad++

Tags: regex, replace, find, notepad++

I am trying to match this regular expression in notepad++, but I am getting an error saying that it is invalid.

My Regex:

```
{{#lsth:JointEntero_May_2015\|2015_May_([0-9]+)}}
```

What I am trying to match:

```
{{#lsth:JointEntero_May_2015|2015_May_8}}
```

Why is it failing?

Comment: try this `\{\{\#lsth\:JointEntero_May_2015\|2015_May_([0-9]+)\}\}`

Comment: [Works here](https://regex101.com/r/sA6wY9/1) Can you add specific detail?

Comment: \{\{\#lsth\:JointEntero_May_2015\|2015_May_([0-9]+)\}\}

This worked. Can someone explain why? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex that works is

```
\{\{\#lsth\:JointEntero_May_2015\|2015_May_([0-9]+)\}\}
```

It is working because the `{` and `}` characters must be escaped in order to get matched as literal symbols. `{}` are usually used as quantifiers where we can set min and/or max characters corresponding to the preceding pattern to match. See [the documentation](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions):

> **{n}**
>   Matches `n` copies of the element it applies to.
>   **{n,}**
>   Matches `n` or more copies of the element it applies to.
>   **{m,n}**
>   Matches m to n copies of the element it applies to, as much it can.
>   **{n,}?,{m,n}?**
>   Like the above, but match as few copies as they can. Compare with *? and friends.